# How to order tr based on td value in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm setting up a table with data which always orders the rows based on the highest value in a td.

I've tried using this function which does sort the rows but then appends new rows into my table so I get replicated rows.

I have my table set up like this and I need to check the TOT column which need to order by highest score.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  sortTable($('#table'), 'asc');
});

function sortTable(table, order) {
  var asc = order === 'asc',
    tbody = table.find('tbody');

  tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a, b) {
    if (asc) {
      return $('td:first', a).text().localeCompare($('td:first', b).text());
    } else {
      return $('td:first', b).text().localeCompare($('td:first', a).text());
    }
  }).appendTo(tbody);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>POS</th>
      <th>TEAM</th>
      <th>DRIVER</th>
      <th>TOT</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>1ST</td>
        <td>PROSPORT PERFORMANCE (85)</td>
        <td>ROBERT RENAUER</td>
        <td>85</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>1ST</td>
        <td>PROSPORT PERFORMANCE (85)</td>
        <td>ROBERT RENAUER</td>
        <td>100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>1ST</td>
        <td>PROSPORT PERFORMANCE (85)</td>
        <td>ROBERT RENAUER</td>
        <td>34</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort by your 'TOT' you have to sort by `td:last` instead of `td:first`.

After this you have to append it to `table` instead of `tbody`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  sortTable($('#table'), 'asc');
});

function sortTable(table, order) {
  var asc = order === 'asc',
    tbody = table.find('tbody');

  tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a, b) {
    if (asc) {
      return $('td:last', a).text().localeCompare($('td:last', b).text());
    } else {
      return $('td:last', b).text().localeCompare($('td:last', a).text());
    }
  }).appendTo(table);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>POS</th>
      <th>TEAM</th>
      <th>DRIVER</th>
      <th>TOT</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>1ST</td>
        <td>PROSPORT PERFORMANCE (85)</td>
        <td>ROBERT RENAUER</td>
        <td>85</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>1ST</td>
        <td>PROSPORT PERFORMANCE (85)</td>
        <td>ROBERT RENAUER</td>
        <td>100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>1ST</td>
        <td>PROSPORT PERFORMANCE (85)</td>
        <td>ROBERT RENAUER</td>
        <td>34</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a HTML issue. The problem is because your first `tr` isn't contained within a `thead` or `tbody`, so it breaks the `table` content. To fix the problem put that `tr` in a `thead`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  sortTable($('#table'), 'desc');
});

function sortTable($table, order) {
  var asc = order === 'asc',
    $tbody = $table.find('tbody');

  $tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a, b) {
    if (asc) {
      return $('td:first', a).text().localeCompare($('td:first', b).text());
    } else {
      return $('td:first', b).text().localeCompare($('td:first', a).text());
    }
  }).appendTo($tbody);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>POS</th>
        <th>TEAM</th>
        <th>DRIVER</th>
        <th>TOT</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>1ST</td>
        <td>PROSPORT PERFORMANCE (85)</td>
        <td>ROBERT RENAUER</td>
        <td>85</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>1ST</td>
        <td>PROSPORT PERFORMANCE (85)</td>
        <td>ROBERT RENAUER</td>
        <td>100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>1ST</td>
        <td>PROSPORT PERFORMANCE (85)</td>
        <td>ROBERT RENAUER</td>
        <td>34</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Also note that you're sorting by string values which may not give the result you require. It may be worth using `parseInt()` on the value of the `td` to improve the sorting reliability.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the sorted rows to the table (`.appendTo(tbody)`). Instead you should replace the children of your tbody with `html` for example.

Your first td of each row is empty, so there is nothing to compare and sort.

But your could should look like below to make it work, if the first td is filled:

```
function sortTable(table, order) {
  var asc = order === 'asc';
  var tbody = table.find('tbody');

  var sorted = tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a, b) {
    console.log(a,b)
    if (asc) return $('td:first', a).text().localeCompare($('td:first', b).text());

    return $('td:first', b).text().localeCompare($('td:first', a).text());

  })

  tbody.html(sorted);
}
```